# Problem span class when edit data on jqgrid and jquery highlight

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, highlight.js

I try to integrate jqgrid and jquery highlight like http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AbhishekSimon11.htm

but i found problem when edit data. When i edit highlighted data, the data become like this:

```
 <span class="highlight">data</span>
```

How to edit without show span class?

Best Regards,

Eka

Comment: Maybe you can clear the highlighted data (see what function to use) before edit. This will solve your problem.

Comment: I got it, Thank you Tony.